Limit Firebase Query for a single child node
The title might imply this is nonsensical, but I'm trying to limit the amount of data retrieved from Firebase.  I have a query structured like this:
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    final Query dataQuery = mFirebaseRef.child("someChild").child(entry.getKey());

    dataQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        // do something with data
    }
}

Each child returned has a timestamp.  Now I want to limit the query further by only returning children in the Map that have timestamp newer than the previous query.
If I form a query such as this:
final Query dataQuery = mFirebaseRef.child("someChild").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(timeMsec);

Then it works and the query returns all children meeting that criteria.
But I want to first limit only to children in the Map (using .child(entry.getKey()), and then check the timestamp values that meet that criteria.  i.e.
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    final Query dataQuery = mFirebaseRef.child("someChild").child(entry.getKey()).orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(timeMsec);
   ... 

And this doesn't work even when children have a timestamp that meet the criteria.  Is this a specific limitation that orderByChild doesn't work when the query returns a single child?  A simple check is to use timeMsec = 0 and nothing is returned by the query.
Here's the json starting at "someChild":
"someChild": {
    "6Pb5K88BiDOKOBlahBlahUID": {
      "activeDays": 2,
      "latest": 200,
      "timestamp": 1713621397890,
      "uid": "6Pb5K88BiDOKOBlahBlahUID",
    },
    "6pDVy45vzsgDYG7BlahBlahUID": {
      "activeDays": 2,
      "latest": 30,
      "timestamp": 1712595611236,
      "uid": "6pDVy45vzsgDYG7BBlahBlahUID",
    },


I'm not sure I understand the query yuo want to build. Can you edit your question to show an example of the JSON (as text, no screenshots please) that you want to query (so someChild and below)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your Firebase Database console.

Thanks for speedy response @FrankvanPuffelen.  The MAP key is obviously the UID

There's no way to query on a specific UID under someChild in that JSON structure, but I'm also not sure what you'd expect the query to do. You can query across all of someChild  for all UIDs with (greater/smaller) a certain timestamp. Or if you want to know whether one specific UID has a timestamp after/before a certain value, you can read the timestamp (someChild/$uid/timestamp) and check it in your code.

I've updated to show another value.  It's a database with lots of exercise data, and you have 2 modes, 1) you can either see everyone's data, or 2) retrieve your favourites which are held in the Map.  It works fine for everyone's data using the .startAt() and it works fine for favourites as indicated in my question without the .startAt().  It's just when I combine the two to limit the data returned for favourites it doesn't return anything.  (some people have a lot of favourites, and I don't want to return data they've already retrieved).

@FrankvanPuffelen To rephrase OP's question as a Firestore query, it would be similar to query(..., where(documentId(), "in", map.keySet()), where("timestamp", ">", timeMsec)) (@SimonHuckett, note that this is psuedo-code, not actual code)

@samthecodingman That won't work as you can only filter on one value (key, property, or value) per query.

There is no way to combine these conditions in a single query. You'll have to load all nodes with a matching timestamp first, and then filter it down on keys client-side - or load all nodes by their keys from the server, and then filter it down on timestamp client-side.
Also see:

Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase


It's a real shame that I cannot get the query to return based on a value within a single node.  Perhaps a good feature request.
